# Stream Data using HTTP using C#

Tags: http, sockets, c#-4.0

Currently I am sending data from client using Socket over TCP.  I need this to be done over HTTP, so that the load balancing can be done at the server side. Any help would be appreciated.  I have added a bit of my code, where I am send the data over TCP.

```
IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textBox1.Text),Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text));
sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
sock.Connect(iep);
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically do a POST to the server every time you want put something there and you do a GET when you want to see if there were any changes.

I haven't tested this code, but it should give you a general idea:

```
public void SendData(byte[] data)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.host.com:80/");

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        writer.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a question posted on extension of this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31603340/streaming-data-from-client-in-c-sharp-over-http". please help